# Passing from Preferences to Activity

Tags: android, preferences

I have one activity - Salary to which I want to pass values (numbers placed in EditTextPreference) from Preferences.

It looks like this:
**ustawienia.xml**:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Przepracowane godziny" 
    android:key="godziny"
    android:summary="Wpisz przepracowane godziny"
    />

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Stawka Godzinowa" 
    android:key="stawka"
    android:summary="Wpisz stawkę godzinową"
    />

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="ZUS" 
    android:key="zus"
    android:summary="Wpisz wielkość składki ZUS"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then Preferences class - **Ustawienia.java**:

```
package com.example.salary;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Ustawienia extends PreferenceActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ustawienia);
}
}
```

Having that I want to take values from preferences to **Salary.java** class to use data.

```
package com.example.salary;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Salary extends Activity {


    Button przelicz;
    TextView brutto, na_czysto;
    EditText netto;

        SharedPreferences wez_ustawienia = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int godziny = wez_ustawienia.getInt("godziny", 21);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_salary);


        przelicz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_przelicz);
        na_czysto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_salary);
        brutto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_brutto);
        netto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_netto);
        przelicz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                double netto_int = Double.valueOf(netto.getText().toString());
                double kasa_brutto = netto_int * 0.25 + netto_int;
                DecimalFormat formatowanie = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                kasa_brutto = Double.valueOf(formatowanie.format(kasa_brutto));
                brutto.setText("Kwota brutto: \t" + kasa_brutto);

                double kasa_na_czysto = (netto_int - 1000);
                //DecimalFormat formatowanie = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                kasa_na_czysto = Double.valueOf(formatowanie.format(kasa_na_czysto));
                na_czysto.setText("Kwota na czysto:\t" + kasa_na_czysto);
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater nadmuchanie = getMenuInflater();
        nadmuchanie.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(item.getItemId()){
      case R.id.oAutorze:
          Intent a = new Intent("com.example.salary.OAUTORZE");
          startActivity(a);
          break;
      case R.id.ustawienia:
          Intent u = new Intent("com.example.salary.USTAWIENIA");
          startActivity(u);
          break;
      case R.id.wyjscie:
          finish();
          break;
      }

      return false;
    }


}
```

However the application crushes just after I added this piece of code:

```
SharedPreferences wez_ustawienia = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        int godziny = wez_ustawienia.getInt("godziny", 21);
```

What's going on with that?
Can I be caused because `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.ustawienia);` is deprecated?

Comment: Mind tagging your question with [tag:android] as well?

Comment: also copy and paste the logs after your app crashes.

Comment: In `SharedPreferences wez_ustawienia = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());` instead of `getBaseContext()`, use `this` Also, it is deprecated in favor of Fragment usage.